# I am trying to set up my detector for a face recognition project or a program,

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, python

but I keep getting this error: 
TypeError: an integer is required (got type tuple)
 my code is :

def DispID(x, y, w, h, NAME, Image):

```
Name_y_pos = y - 10
Name_X_pos = x + w / 2 - (len(NAME) * 7 / 2)

if Name_X_pos < 0:
    Name_X_pos = 0
elif (Name_X_pos + 10 + (len(NAME) * 7) > Image.shape[1]):
    Name_X_pos = Name_X_pos - (Name_X_pos + 10 + (len(NAME) * 7) - (Image.shape[1]))
if Name_y_pos < 0:
    Name_y_pos = Name_y_pos = y + h + 10


draw_box(Image, x, y, w, h)

cv2.rectangle(Image, (int(Name_X_pos) - 10, int(Name_y_pos) - 25), (int(Name_X_pos) + 10 + (len(NAME) * 7), int(Name_y_pos) - 1), (0, 0, 0), -2)           # Draw a Black Rectangle over the face frame
cv2.rectangle(Image, (Name_X_pos - 10, Name_y_pos - 25), (Name_X_pos + 10 + (int(len(NAME)) * 7), Name_y_pos - 1), WHITE, 1)
cv2.putText(Image, NAME, (Name_X_pos, Name_y_pos - 10), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_DUPLEX, .4, WHITE)
```

Error log : cv2.rectangle(Image, (int(Name_X_pos) - 10, int(Name_y_pos) - 25), (int(Name_X_pos) + 10 + (len(NAME) * 7), int(Name_y_pos) - 1), (0, 0, 0), -2) TypeError: an integer is required (got type tuple)

Answer (score 0):

Due to some division made to define Name_X_pos you can have a assume a float number, which is not allowed in the rectangle function.


I know the error was not saying anything about float number, but about tuple. I had to test line by line  to find the solution.


That's the modification I made:

```
<!-- language: python -->
cv2.rectangle(img, (int(Name_X_pos) - 10, int(Name_y_pos) - 25), (int(Name_X_pos) + 10 + (len(NAME) * 7), int(Name_y_pos) - 1), (0, 0, 0), -2)  # Draw a Black Rectangle over the face frame
cv2.rectangle(img, (int(Name_X_pos) - 10, Name_y_pos - 25), (int(Name_X_pos) + 10 + int(len(NAME)) * 7, Name_y_pos - 1), WHITE, 1)
cv2.putText(img, NAME, (int(Name_X_pos), Name_y_pos - 10), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_DUPLEX, .4, WHITE)
```

Result:
[image]